# Elastic Search: How to give weight for length of matched string

Tags: python, elasticsearch

i have data (1800 rows)

in the data there is two string:

"st ali" and
"santo borromeus"

when i do searching process using elastic search with query "st borromeus", the result returned "st ali" , i know it's because "st" give higher score than "borromeus" (maybe because of tfidf calculation), but it will be more logical if it returns "santo borromeus" because "borromeus" longer than "st"

so i want to make custom scoring to multiply the score by length of matched word ?

i used elasticsearch python packages ?

Have somebody do this before?